# Make a call in Objective C help!

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I need to make a call where it says add call here. Can someone help?

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView 
       shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
       navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)ntype {

       NSLog(@"Scheme: %@", request.URL.scheme);
       if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"save"]) {

        //Add Call here
    }

    return true;
}
```

From this code:

```
- (void) save {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size); 
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);

    NSLog(@"TEST");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading the question correctly, you're probably looking to do something like:

```
[self save];
```

Assuming that the `save` message is declared in the same class. If the `save` message is in a different class, and you have an instance of that class, it'd look like:

```
[foo save];
```

Where `foo` is the name of the variable whose class contains the `save` method.

Either way, this is the standard means of "calling a method" (or, sending a message, in the Objective-C world).

Comment: Yes, - (void)save; is declared in my header file. But [instanceVariableName save]; doesnt work.

Comment: If it's in the same class, go with `[self save];`